# How reset password in Jenkins in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

i download `jenkins.war` and put in `$TOMCAT_HOME/web-app/jenkins.war` i set settings using tutorial vogella but I forgot my password, where I can find a file from password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Ubuntu you need go to folder `home/[user name]/.jenkins` and your password is this folder.

Comment: `ls -a` or `Ctrl+H`, if you install jenkins from terminal your home page locale on `/var/lib/jenkins`

Answer (score 4):

if it is windows  just go to

> C:\Users\yourusername.jenkins\secrets

and you will find  initialAdminPassword file 
just use that as a password

Comment: I am using windows and the password from "initialAdminPassword" worked for me.
But how do I change the password of "admin" user. Simply changing content of the above file does not work, and it still uses the old password even after I restart the tomcat. Probably I need to do some more steps. 
Can anybody help?